# SQL Get Total number of Output

Tags: sql-server

I would like to get the total result of row. For example, if the database have 10 records, so the output should be 10.

My query is this

```
select COUNT(*) AS NumberRow from
(SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT [EmpName], sum(Scoring) as GrandTotal
FROM [masterView] GROUP BY [EmpName] 
ORDER BY GrandTotal DESC,EmpName ASC)
```

But there is an error:-

The error is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should alias subquery:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS NumberRow
FROM    ( SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT
                    [EmpName] ,
                    SUM(Scoring) AS GrandTotal
          FROM      [masterView]
          GROUP BY  [EmpName]
          ORDER BY  GrandTotal DESC ,
                    EmpName ASC
        ) t
```

You can mix data with aggregations using window function like:

```
SELECT  *, COUNT(*) OVER() AS NumberRow
FROM    ( SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT
                    [EmpName] ,
                    SUM(Scoring) AS GrandTotal
          FROM      [masterView]
          GROUP BY  [EmpName]
          ORDER BY  GrandTotal DESC ,
                    EmpName ASC
        ) t
```

Comment: @RahulTripathi, yes but then there is redundant columns selects `[EmpName] ,
                    SUM(Scoring) AS GrandTotal`

Comment: Thank You @GiorgiNakeuri. the COUNT is not working together WITH TIES? just for my information only, is not important. =)

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, oh, meaning i cant get the actual NumberRow if i COUNT the TOP with ties.

Comment: See:

`SELECT  *, COUNT(*) OVER() AS NumberRow
FROM    ( SELECT TOP 30 PERCENT WITH TIES
                    [EmpName] ,
                    SUM(Scoring) AS GrandTotal
          FROM      [masterView]
          GROUP BY  [EmpName]
          ORDER BY  GrandTotal DESC ,
                    EmpName ASC
        ) t`

Comment: It repeat the Number Row, for example if there is 53 display output, the NumberRow = 53

Comment: @KelvinFoo, if you want just a count, use ties with first select statement in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alias thing would definitely work as Giorgi has mentioned above. But if your database has 10 records of Employees, your query would return only 3 records instead of 10 as you are selecting TOP 30 PERCENT. The below query should return 10 records.

```
select COUNT(*) AS NumberRow from
(   SELECT [EmpName], sum(Scoring) as GrandTotal
    FROM [masterView] GROUP BY [EmpName] 
    ORDER BY GrandTotal DESC,EmpName ASC
)temp
```